# Plugin or theme that sort posts as 'top this year' and 'top last month"?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Is there any free  WordPress plugin or theme that sort posts as 'top this year' and 'top last month" or 'top 24 hours' based on voting?

I'm using [the Vote It Up plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/) right now. But it doesn't have the capability of sorting post as a loop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try GD Star Rating - I'm pretty sure it stores vote times and so can be used to do this - you'll probably need to extract the ordering yourself though.

http://www.gdstarrating.com/

Answer (score 1):

Until the plugin switches to storing votes differently there's going to be no nice way to sort based on votes.

Take a look at a row from the votes table.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | post |  votes  | guests | usersinks | guestsinks |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1234 | ,1,2,3  |        |           |            |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

All the votes for users are being stored in a singular column(votes), and MySQL has no proper way to split, count and order based on that column.

Perhaps some MySQL ninja can create a procedure/function to do it, but that's beyond my SQL know-how.

Not sure why the author choose to store votes that way, but from a result sorting perspective that's a poor DB design decision(imo).

I appreciate i havn't really addressed the question, but thought it might be nice to point out while it may be something that is easy in theory, there's a good reason the author hasn't provided this facility with the plugin already - his db design makes sorting based on vote extremely hard(at the SQL level at least).

This is what i'd do if i was writing such a plugin..

Use one new table for holding just the votes, all votes..

Here's some imaginary data in the table.

```
Table: wp_post_votes
Type: new
+--------------------------------------------+
|  ID    |  post_id |  user_id  |  type      |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  1     |  123     |   10      |  up        |
|  2     |  123     |   22      |  down      |
|  3     |  123     |   4       |  up        |
|  4     |  123     |   1       |  up        |
|  5     |  25      |   6       |  up        |
|  6     |  25      |   10      |  up        |
|  7     |  25      |   1       |  down      |
|  8     |  25      |   2       |  up        |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Alongside that i'd use usermeta and postmeta to store vote counts for both the posts and users voting.

Here's some imaginary meta data to help visualize.

```
Table: wp_postmeta
Type: core, existing
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  meta_id  |  post_id   |   meta_key   |   meta_value      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  512      |   123      |  vote_count  |        4          |
|  513      |   25       |  vote_count  |        4          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

Table: wp_usermeta
Type: core, existing
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  umeta_id  |  user_id  |  meta_key   |  meta_value        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  443       |   1       |  vote_count |       2            |
|  445       |   2       |  vote_count |       1            |
|  442       |   4       |  vote_count |       1            |
|  444       |   6       |  vote_count |       1            |
|  440       |   10      |  vote_count |       2            |
|  441       |   22      |  vote_count |       1            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

That way the posts could be sorted based on meta value and additionally leveraging the meta tables would mean quick access to update and fetch functions, like `get_user_meta`, `get_post_meta`, `update_post_meta` ... and so on..(i'm sure you get the point).

Just thinking out loud, because your question had me thinking about how i'd do it differently..

Comment: And you would also need to record the time of the votes to get "top this week", "top this month", ... summaries.

Comment: If you wanted that kind of data, sure... :)